# How to convert object array into string, PHP

Tags: php

Using `$results->created_by = $data->query->results->created_by;`

**below is what $results returns**

> cc\test\testfolder\RequestSubData Object (
>       [created_by] => cc\test\testfolder\RequestSubData Object
>           (
>               [0] => nick
>           )
>   )

**How do I convert above $results into below?**

> cc\test\testfolder\RequestSubData Object (
>       [created_by] => nick )

How do I remove `cc\test\testfolder\RequestSubData Object`

I have tried `$results->created_by = changeArrayToString($data->query->results->created_by);`
But still the same.

Please assist, Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an API? Where did you get that data's?

Answer (score 0):

Properties with numeric names have to be accessed specially:

```
$results->created_by = $results->created_by->{"0"}
```